# Did Vasishta's brother sage Agastya have a previous birth?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, rebirth, vashishta, agastya

Most people only know about the fact the famous sage Vasishta, guru of Rama, was one of the mind-born sons of Brahma.  What's not as well-known, however, is the fact that Vasishta is no longer the son of Brahma!  In fact if you look at the Anukramani for Rig Veda Book 7 in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36), you'll find Vasishta listed not as Vasishta son of Brahma, but rather "Vasishta Maitravaruni", i.e. Vasishta son of Mitra and Varuna.  Let me explain.

Once the ancient king Nimi, ancestor of Janaka, wanted to conduct a Yagna, so he asked the sage Vasishta to be his priest.  Vasishta told Nimi that he had already promised to conduct a Yagna for Indra, so he would conduct Nimi's Yagna afterward.  But Nimi didn't want to wait, so he hired someone else to be his priest.  When Vasishta found out about this, he was furious, and cursed Nimi to have his soul separated from his body.  In response, Nimi uttered the same curse back to Vasishta, so Vasishta's body died and Vasishta's soul was left to wander.  Finally, when the gods Mitra (god of friendship) and Varuna (the ocean god) produced two children out of attraction to the Apsara Urvashi, Vasishta was reborn as one of those children, the other being the famous sage Agastya.  [Here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/13/chapter-view) is how the Srimad Bhagavatam describes it:

> After beginning sacrifices, Mahārāja Nimi, the son of Ikṣvāku, requested the great sage Vasiṣṭha to take the post of chief priest. At that time, Vasiṣṭha replied, “My dear Mahārāja Nimi, I have already accepted the same post in a sacrifice begun by Lord Indra.  I shall return here after finishing the yajña for Indra. Kindly wait for me until then.” Mahārāja Nimi remained silent, and Vasiṣṭha began to perform the sacrifice for Lord Indra.  Mahārāja Nimi, being a self-realized soul, considered that this life is flickering. Therefore, instead of waiting long for Vasiṣṭha, he began performing the sacrifice with other priests.  After completing the sacrificial performance for King Indra, the spiritual master Vasiṣṭha returned and found that his disciple Mahārāja Nimi had disobeyed his instructions. Thus Vasiṣṭha cursed him, saying, “May the material body of Nimi, who considers himself learned, immediately fall.”
>
> For unnecessarily cursing him when he had committed no offense, Mahārāja Nimi countercursed his spiritual master. “For the sake of getting contributions from the King of heaven,” he said, “you have lost your religious intelligence. Therefore I pronounce this curse: your body also will fall.  After saying this, Mahārāja Nimi, who was expert in the science of spiritual knowledge, gave up his body. Vasiṣṭha, the great-grandfather, gave up his body also, but through the semen discharged by Mitra and Varuṇa when they saw Urvaśī, he was born again.

[This earlier chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/18/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam provides a bit more detail about the birth of Vasishta and Agastya:

> Agastya and Vasiṣṭha Ṛṣis were the common sons of Varuṇa and Mitra, the tenth son of Aditi.  Upon seeing Urvaśī, the celestial society girl, both Mitra and Varuṇa discharged semen, which they preserved in an earthen pot. The two sons Agastya and Vasiṣṭha later appeared from that pot, and they are therefore the common sons of Mitra and Varuṇa.

My question is, was this the main birth of the sage Agastya?  Given that Vasishta was originally a sage born from Brahma and then later reborn as the son of Mitra and Varuna, is it possible that something similar happened in Agastya's case?

Do any scriptures describe a previous birth of Agastya?

Comment: Why would indra  conduct yajna? I thought yajna is conducted by humans on devas to different purposes.

Comment: @sysinit The gods conduct Yagnas all the time, to obtain success in defeating the Asuras and things like that.  Here's an example of such a Yagna: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6682/36

Comment: @sysinit In fact, the whole reason the gods have a guru, Brihaspati, is to conduct Yagnas to benefit them.  And that is why Indra killed his temporary guru Trisiras, because Trisiras was conducting Yagnas to benefit both the Devas and the Asuras: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2408/36

Comment: Ok , when humans typically conduct yajna , they offer oblations to indra,varuna etc via agni . But when devas conduct yajna , whom they offer oblations?(Brahma , vishnu , ishvara?)

Comment: Also where would they conduct yajna? In svarga loka?

Comment: @sysinit Well, usually what happens is that they have a priest conduct the Yagna for them, and then the gods' priest will offer oblations to the gods.  And sometimes it's done in Devaloka, but other times it's done on Earth.  Like the Yagna by which Yama became the god of death was conducted in the Naimisharanya forest, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6682/36  But I haven't really heard of gods offering Yagna oblations to Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva, except the famous Yagna described in the Purusha Sukta where Brahma made offerings to Vishnu.

Comment: Thanks . But what is the use of gods offering oblations to themselves?. Does offering oblations to themselves make them stronger?

Comment: @sysini Yeah, the gods derive power from Yagnas.  As the Vishnu Purana says, "havisham parinamoyam yat etad akhilam jagat" - the whole world is but a transformation of the Yagna oblation.  That is why the gods were concerned when Hiranyaksha put the Earth in the water, and when Kaushika's wife prevented the sun from rising as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1984/36 It's because they didn't want the Yagnas to stop, since they need the power of the Yagnas.

Comment: Does that mean that , when humans stops performing yajnas , gods would be weaker?. If that is the case , in every kaliyuga where atheism would peak, people would  not perform yajnas, Hence gods should be weakest.

Comment: Also I believe yajnas starts only in treta yuga, So how will gods receive oblation in satya yuga?

Comment: @sysinit Well, perhaps Yagnas are still being performed in Devaloka to compensate for humans not performing that.  In any case, Yagnas don't start in Treta Yuga, it's just that Treta Yuga is when Yagnas are the most popular form of religious activity.

Comment: Here is the story of bhagavatam , which says" on advent of treta yuga ,  process of performing yajna to fulfill fruitive activities, appeared within  heart of pururava" http://vedabase.net/sb/9/14/43/en2

Comment: @sysinit Yeah, that just means that Yagnas are the main form of worship in the Treta Yuga, so when the Treta Yuga began Pururavas was blessed with the rules of how to do Yagnas.  But that doesn't mean Yagnas are never done in the Satya Yuga.  You can do all four kinds of activities (Tapasya, Yagna, Pancharatra, and Sankirtana) in all four Yugas, it's just a change in emphasis.

Comment: @sysinit There's plenty of examples of Yagnas done in the Satya Yuga.  For instance, the Anushasana Parva of the Mahabharata says "He also who in the Krita age adored the gods in a grand Gomedha sacrifice, viz., Rantideva of great splendour, who was equal unto Mahadeva himself, should be named. Endued with penances, possessed of every auspicious mark, the source of every kind of benefit to the world, he was the conqueror of the universes." http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b115.htm I discuss Rantideva in more detail here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6728/36

Comment: Also, the famous story of Sati Devi immolating in the Yagna fire(or Yog agni in some interpretations) during the Yagna conducted by Prajapati Daksh took place in Satya Yuga.

Comment: @Naveen I know it was conducted during the Swayambhuva Manvantara of the Pitri Kalpa (the Kalpa before this one), but I wasn't aware of the Yuga.  Where did you hear that it was in the Satya Yuga?

Comment: I have seen multiple references in brahmanda purana, which gives example of how yawns began to function in treta yuga.Many references in chapter 35 talks about that . Even in chapter 34 , they talk about how different mantras began to function in first treta yuga of swayambhuva manvantara, which were existed in previous kalpa

Comment: @sysinit What verses in chapters 34 and 35 are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry My mistake , it should be chapter 30. In the first verse of chapter 30, it has got following quote .Desciples ask "How could Yajña begin to function formerly in the Svayambhuva Manvantara, at the beginning of the Treta Yuga.".

Comment: In Chapter 29, verse 47-48 , it says that "In the first Treta Yuga, those.Mantras along with Taraka (i.e. Orhk‚ra) and other examples manifested themselves without any conscious effort or previous knowledge, unto the seven sages and Manu.

Comment: In chapter 29, verse 49-50 , it says that "Those Siddhis (spiritual powers and achievements) which appeared before the Devas in the first Kalpa, of their own accord (appeared before these also i.e. seven sages and
Manu). When the original Siddhis ceased to exist, others began
to function. Thousands of those Mantras which existed in the
Kalpas gone by manifested themselves in their intellect once
again.

Comment: @sysinit Yes, that just means that when the Treta Yuga arrived, knowledge of Yagnas appeared in the minds of men because Yagnas are the main form of worship in the Treta Yuga.  But that doesn't mean that Yagnas are never performed in the Satya Yuga.  I gave you the example of Rantideva's Gomedha Yagna earlier.

Comment: Atleast in first statya yuga ,There were no mantras to perform yajnas. Still trying to find reference for other satya yugas.

Comment: In chapter 31 , it talks about siddhis (not mantras for yajnas). It says "Siddhis prevalent during the Sandhyās of Yugas become reduced to three-fourths in the following Yugas Siddhis prevalent, in the Yugas become reduced to three-fourths in the following Sandhyās"

Comment: Does it mean indirectly , there is something like laws of physics for each yuga? .For example mantras didn't exist in first satya yuga . They MANIFESTED  in first treta yuga. Some siddhis appeared in some yugas, don't exist in other yugas .

Comment: @sysinit The mantras of the Vedas were definitely known in the Satya Yuga, but then they were reintroduced to humanity in the Treta Yuga.  This is mentioned in either chapter 34 or 35 (which I accidentally read because you mentioned them).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Agastya is an incarnation of both Agni and Vayu.**  I found the answer in [this excerpt](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/23277/25F_Chapter_61_1.pdf) from the Matsya Puranas.  Once a bunch of Asuras hid themselves in the ocean, so Indra ordered Agni and Vayu to dry up the ocean.  But Agni and Vayu refused, because the ocean is home to so many creatures.  Indra was furious, and cursed them to take birth as a sage:

> There is no question of Dharma or Adharma where Immortals are concerned, and your glory is still more high.  O Agni and Vayu!  Since you have violated my injunction and have the duties of the Munis not to injure any being, and since you have leaned towards the enemies who are devoid of religion and politics, losing sight of duty and Shastra, therefore You, O fire will now be born along with Maruta, among mortals, in the form of a sage.  In that form of the sage Agastya, you will dry up the ocean, after which you will again come back to your Divine form.

And sure enough, Agastya did swallow up the ocean to help the gods defeat the Asuras.  He hasn't regained his divine form(s) yet though, because he received a boon that he will remain alive for 250 billion Mahakalpas!  (A Mahakalpas is 100 years in the life of Brahma, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36)).

On a side note, it is Agastya's swallowing of the ocean that ultimately led to the descent of the Ganga from Devaloka.  Once Vishnu's incarnation Kapila, whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3672/36), burnt the sons of Sagara to ashes, but their ashes could not be scattered because the ocean had dried up.  That is why Sagara's descendant Bhagiratha had to get the Ganga to come down to Earth, to replenish the ocean and scatter the ashes in a worthy body of water.

Comment: So Agastya is 2 person and presently there is no Agni dev and Vayu dev in this universe?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, they're still there, they just had to take an incarnation as Agastya.  It's similar to how the Vasus were cursed to be born as the sons of Shantanu and Ganga; they still existed as gods, they just also had incarnations on Earth.

Comment: Then that curse is useless if they are still in their original form and you also said in your answer that Agastya hasn't regained his divine form yet.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, it's not useless, because while Agni and Vayu are in Devalokw, they have to simultaneously experience life as a human.  It's similar to what happened to the Vasus.  Dyaus Pita was still living in Deva Loka, but he had to simultaneously experience the suffering of living as Bhishma.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are suffering in human form because atleast they are aware of their deva form so that suffering is not same as the suffering of normal human beings.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, it's still worse for them to experience life as a human being than not experience that.

Comment: If Agastya is still aware of his original form then there is no concept of suffering. Just like realized souls don't get carried away by different emotions arised from the veils of Maya, Agastya must also be free from such matters.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well right now it may not be a punishment anymore, but at least from Agastya's birth until he attained Jnana, Agni and Vayu would have experienced suffering.

Comment: Where did you get that 250 billion **Mahakalpas** story? It's seems too crazy to be factual.

Comment: @Surya I got it from the beginning of page 240 of that Matsya Purana excerpt I linked to.  "Agastya said, "I wish to move about...'"

Comment: That verse has a big bold lettered screaming **Interpolation** all over it. Why would Agastya, the realised Rishi, ask **such a materialistic** thing? If Agastya really HAD said such a thing, I would despise him till the end of creation.

Comment: @Surya First of all, it's a bad idea to reject a passage because the incident described sounds far-fetched; it's a well-established principle of Mimamsa that even in the case of scriptural verses that talk about trees sitting down (!), we should accept them as genuine verses unless we find semantic or syntactic reasons to doubt them.  Second of all, Rishis ask for immortality all the time; Agastya would be able to better help the denizens of the three worlds if he had such incredible longevity.

Comment: @Surya I, on the other hand, have inordinate respect for him; with his longevity, he was able to instigate the descent of the Ganga, he lead Rama to fight Ravana, he gave Tamil to us, he established Nadi astrology, and who knows what lofty deeds he'll do in future ages!

Comment: All that is fine, but that is not what is (supposedly) asked. He didn't say, "Please make me live for so many 1000s of Brahma's lifetimes, so that I can serve this world." He said, "Please make me live for so long so that I can roam around in a plane and obtain the worship (read kowtowing) of people." Which is not what a great rishi like Agastya Muni would ask. Hence I say so.

Comment: Plus, his boon made in the presence of Brahma would be a huge disrespect for Brahma, which surely Agastya wouldn't do.

Comment: @Surya The moving about in a Vimana part would allow him to freely travel among the worlds doing good for living beings.  Asking that his devotees accrue great benefits isn't a plea for more devotees; I think Agastya knew he would have devotees, and so he wanted to bless those devotees as much as possible.  And it doesn't show the slightest disrespect to Brahma.

Comment: @Surya This is exactly the sort of boon I can imagine the Alwars asking for.  I can easily imagine Nammalwar asking Vishnu, "I ask that those who utter Madhurakavi Alwar's Kannanin Sirithambu in praise of me should attain your lotus feet."

Comment: Yeah, Nammazhvar asked for them to attain His lotus feet; but here the verse says, "Let them be the overlord of the seven realms." There is no comparison to Krsna's Feet and the Kingship of Seven (Boring and Bothersome) worlds.

Comment: @Surya Showering material benefits upon your devotees is not an unusual thing for a Rishi to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31309/discussion-between-surya-and-keshav-srinivasan).

Answer (score 3):

**[Shrimad Bhagvatam Chapter 4 Verse 1.36](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Dfk2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=srimad%20bhagavatam%20visrava%20agastya&source=bl&ots=xXMww64QHa&sig=p9xMEfcUfvrOiSkyTFXdNahCKSs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW0_vEyaHVAhWDHJQKHfyOACkQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=srimad%20bhagavatam%20visrava%20agastya&f=false)** mentions the following about the birth of Agastya:

[image]

He was called Dahragni or Jatharagni in an earlier birth which may relate to the story of Agni being cursed to be born as Agastya as well as the story of his digesting Vatapi (since Jatharagni in Ayurved refers to the digestive fire). The **[Vishnu Puran Chapter X](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=FCFC_bdqOPQC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=jatharagni%20agastya&source=bl&ots=OB5AEg4WCJ&sig=Nh6FpgGCoAhZKx-mC8JFs7sKjM4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHrLOVzqHVAhXMo5QKHbJ-AegQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=jatharagni%20agastya&f=false)** also mentions him being born to Pulatsya which would again testify to his kinship with Vishrava:

> The wife of Angiras, Smriti, bore daughters named Siniválí, Kuhu, Ráká, and Anumati (phases of the moon). Anasúyá, the wife of Atri, was the mother of three sinless sons, Soma (the moon), Durvásas, and the ascetic Dattátreya. **Pulastya had, by Príti, a son called in a former birth, or in the Swáyambhuva Manwantara, Dattoli, who is now known as the sage Agastya.**

So the birth from Mitra-Varun could be the second birth (just as it was a rebirth of Vasishth) while the first birth of Jatharagni/Dattoli took place in Swayambhu Manvantar.

Comment: There seems some translation issue if we check original verse of Vishnu Puran Chapter X as discussed in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29092/12304 post..This is next birth..but you are claiming it as previous birth...