# Why is Ganga called Sursari?

Tags: ganga

http://www.hindi2dictionary.com/paryayvachi/sursari.html

the Hindi dictionary gives

> शब्द   पर्यायवाची
> सुरसरि  त्रिपथगा, जाह्नवी, सुरसरिता, सुरधुनी, गंगा, देवनदी, मंदाकनी, भगीरथी, विश्नुपगा, देवपगा, ध्रुवनंदा
> Sursari Tripthaga, Jahanvi, Sursarita, Surdhuni, Ganga, Devnadi, Mandakani, Bhagirathi, Vishnupaga, Devpaga, Dhruvnanda

Comment: Because it originally flowed only in swarga (devata abode) before being brought down to earth by Bhagiratha. It is actually the river of the Devatas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Sura* (सुर) means, a *devtaa*. 
*Sari* (सरि or सरी),  is to be taken for the word *Saritã* (सरिता) i.e, a river.

Since *Gangā* is said to be flowing in the *[swargaloka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10144/17833)*  first, and thus it is always in vicinity of gods (सुर), hence, it's also called as *Sursari*.

Again, as per [several stories in the different *puranas*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27085/what-is-the-origin-of-ganga?r=SearchResults), it is in some way or other, connected to all the three deities of the *Trimurti Godhead*. They are also to be called great *sura* (सुर), - *Brahmaa*. *Vishnu*, & *Shiva*.

And thus, owing to her connection with several different gods (*suras* - सुर), Gangā, is thus called *surasari* (सुरसरि)

---

- Some explicit references to Gangā as *Sursari*.

As *Goswami Tulasīdāsa* says in a couplet in *[Bala Kanda](https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/ramcharitmanas?page=0%2C13)*

> कीरति, मणिति, मेलि सोई।
> **सुरसरि** सम सब कर हितु होई।।

Meaning - Popularity, Prose and Pelf, these three are only worthy if and only if, when they are as auspicious and useful as the River Ganga (*Sursari*)

Further, in the *Rāmacharitamanasa*, *Ayodhya Kaanda*,  [[1.2.132](https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/content/12132)] , he makes references to Ganga as *Sursari*, which is river Ganga only, called by *Mandakini* (मंदाकिनी - meaning, one that flows slowly (मंद) ), that flows in the Heaven (*swarga*) realms.

> नदी पुनीत पुरान बखानी। अत्रिप्रिया निज तप बल आनी॥
> **सुरसरि** धार नाउँ मंदाकिनि। जो सब पातक पोतक डाकिनि॥3॥